# ERROR:0@0.013 ; ERROR:0@0.045: haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml' in read mode , getStreamChannelGroup Camera index out of range

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition, face-detection, haar-classifier

when i try to execute the code i get this error, someone know the solution ?

```
import cv2

# Method to generate dataset to recognize a person
def generate_dataset(img, id, img_id):
    # write image in data dir
    cv2.imwrite("data/user."+str(id)+"."+str(img_id)+".jpg", img)

# Method to draw boundary around the detected feature
def draw_boundary(img, classifier, scaleFactor, minNeighbors, color, text):
    # Converting image to gray-scale
    gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # detecting features in gray-scale image, returns coordinates, width and height of features
    features = classifier.detectMultiScale(gray_img, scaleFactor, minNeighbors)
    coords = []
    # drawing rectangle around the feature and labeling it
    for (x, y, w, h) in features:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), color, 2)
        cv2.putText(img, text, (x, y-4), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, color, 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
        coords = [x, y, w, h]
    return coords

# Method to detect the features
def detect(img, faceCascade, img_id):
    color = {"blue":(255,0,0), "red":(0,0,255), "green":(0,255,0), "white":(255,255,255)}
    coords = draw_boundary(img, faceCascade, 1.1, 10, color['blue'], "Face")
    # If feature is detected, the draw_boundary method will return the x,y coordinates and width and height of rectangle else the length of coords will be 0
    if len(coords)==4:
        # Updating region of interest by cropping image
        roi_img = img[coords[1]:coords[1]+coords[3], coords[0]:coords[0]+coords[2]]
        # Assign unique id to each user
        user_id = 1
        # img_id to make the name of each image unique
        generate_dataset(roi_img, user_id, img_id)

    return img


# Loading classifiers
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')


# Capturing real time video stream. 0 for built-in web-cams, 0 or -1 for external web-cams
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)

# Initialize img_id with 0
img_id = 0

while True:
    if img_id % 50 == 0:
        print("Collected ", img_id," images")
    # Reading image from video stream
    _, img = video_capture.read()
    # Call method we defined above
    img = detect(img, faceCascade, img_id)
    # Writing processed image in a new window
    cv2.imshow("face detection", img)
    img_id += 1
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# releasing web-cam
video_capture.release()
# Destroying output window
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

```
/Face-Detection-Recognition-Using-OpenCV-in-Python-master/collect_training_data.py"
[ERROR:0@0.013] global persistence.cpp:505 cv::FileStorage::Impl::open Can't open file: 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml' in read mode
[ERROR:0@0.045] global obsensor_uvc_stream_channel.cpp:156 cv::obsensor::getStreamChannelGroup Camera index out of range
Collected  0  images
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\x\Downloads\Face-Detection-Recognition-Using-OpenCV-in-Python-master (1)\Face-Detection-Recognition-Using-OpenCV-in-Python-master\collect_training_data.py", line 54, in <module>
    img = detect(img, faceCascade, img_id)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\x\Downloads\Face-Detection-Recognition-Using-OpenCV-in-Python-master (1)\Face-Detection-Recognition-Using-OpenCV-in-Python-master\collect_training_data.py", line 25, in detect
    coords = draw_boundary(img, faceCascade, 1.1, 10, color['blue'], "Face")
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\x\Downloads\Face-Detection-Recognition-Using-OpenCV-in-Python-master (1)\Face-Detection-Recognition-Using-OpenCV-in-Python-master\collect_training_data.py", line 11, in draw_boundary
    gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```